# Java Open Source Projects to be used in teaching

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to assemble a workshop on OOP using Java and one of the things I want to try is to do a sort of autopsy of an application.

The ideia is to show the advantages os OOP through a real-life example of one, or more, complex applications.

My question is: can you sugest a good open-source java project, that is currently under development, and as a bonus is a application that is useful for college students.

Thanks in advance

Ricardo Gomes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* use Eclipse. That thing is gigantic. It would take an *experienced* programmer a couple of months just to figure out how it all fits together.

How about [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/hsqldb/base/trunk/)? It's a mature project that's used in the real world, and it's fairly complex - but it's also limited in what it tries to do, so the complexity is still manageable.

Comment: I agree with the statement about Eclipse, but I think recommending HSQL goes in the other direction.  Not only is it a complex framework, it would require the students to learn SQL at the same time, and I can't make assumptions about their other programming skills.

Comment: Interesting option. And the ideia is not to have the students learn how everything works, but to choose a particular part to better explain the OO concepts, and why they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a stretch, but if your goal is to get students engaged it may not be.

Take a look at IBM's [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/).  It's an open source Java programming game.  You could build / download some existing bots and do your autopsy on them.  You could also implement a bot in a very non-OOP manor and refactor it into something more OO.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I actually already used RoboCode on a training session. But the ideia here was to realize the usefulness of OOP in an existing application, not necessarily commercial but along does lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look here: http://java-source.net/

My personal one would be something like Eclipse, which everyone uses, works well (enough), is very extensible, and written in Java. But of-course, that's a huge application

Comment: I'll look into it. And yes Eclipse might be a bit oversized, but its still an interesting option. Thanks